# Rule of Thumb for PCB pad sizes of SMD devices?

Tags: surface-mount, footprint, pad

I am trying to make a PCB for the first time and am concerned about the sizes of the soldering pads over the actual dimensions that I should realize on the board. That is, with the following diagram:

[image]

What size should the top pin's pad be? The dimensions for this pin are given as 3.00 x 1.75 mm. About what size should the associated soldering pad be and what (if any) is the general rule?

Comment: The rule of thumb is "read the datasheet".

Comment: Clearly this is from the datasheet. Some of the datasheets include recommended pads, this one did not.

Comment: Not necessarily the component datasheet. Some manufacturers have discrete package-specific datasheets.

Comment: I will look into that.

Answer (score 4):

The drawing in the O.P. comes from a datasheet.  Some datasheets have a dimensioned drawing for the footprint (land pattern).  Here's an example.  Notice that the pads (top right corner) a somewhat wider than the legs.

[image]
Originally from [here](http://diodes.com/catalog/single_ldos_66/ap7365.html).  Found this by googling *SOT-223*.

SOT-223 is a fairly common package.  It's likely that your layout software has a standard footprint for it.  There's a good chance that it's accurate.

Answer (score 2):

Depends on how you will be soldering components - I'd add a bit of margin if I intend to hand solder - think of where it would be convenient to access with the soldering iron, leave standard sizes from datasheet for reflow.